# Django first run: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Hi, I just installed django and I'm running through the starter tutorials and when I enter the first command:

```
$ python -m django --version
```

I get an error stating: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Why am I getting this? I am brand new to django.

Comment: Please show the entire error message. Are you using python3? How did you install django?

Comment: Show us the full error and even a snippet of the line. Check Parentheses also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have at least two pips installed shipped with different versions of python executable, try to set up the virtual environment first then you will not have this issue.